# Make Lua use my C++ factory method to create objects?

Tags: c++, lua, game-engine

I found some similar questions, but none of them fit my situation, and I am too newbie in this C++ - Lua binding. **(I use LuaBridge.)**

I want to make Lua scripts for my GameObject (yes, this is a game engine), and currently I am working on defining a *"C++ interface"* for the scripts.

My problem is that I want to make new GameObjects, and currently is done by calling the `Scene's CreateGameObject` method which

- for example checks, that is the new GameObject creatable. (like name duplication)
- If everythign is correct, it creates it, places in the container, and returns a pointer to it.

**My question is:**

- How can I bind this method to a Lua object's constructor, so then later I can use the previously binded functions of this new Lua Object?

  - (I binded the C++ GameObject's methods to Lua's GameObject functions)
- Or I should rework this factory method things, like this:

  - Instead of using Scene's CreateGameObject methods, just use `new GameObject(...);`
  - GameObject's constructor calls the Scene's `GameObjectConstructed` method, which will handle the previously Scene related checks, element inserting, etc.
  - I think this version is viable, but now there isn't a precheck for creating a GameObject, instead a postcheck.

I hope my question is understandable. Thanks in advance!